# Can you use your computer to make a radio transmitter?

Tags: radio, crystal

I was wondering, is it possible to oscillate the electronic signal emitted from the audio jack on a computer ? Because I would like to somehow create a simple radio transmitter just using my computer.

Comment: Yes, sort of. But don't expect to be able to do much with it.

Comment: As for radio... ah no, sound cards usually top out at maybe 24kHz afaik.

Comment: Not the audio jack, and I'm not aware of how to do it on a PC.  On a Raspberry Pi it is possible to use a timer output to generate FM radio: http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter  It should also be possible with some microcontrollers, for example the LPC43xx.

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but you might find Software Defined Radio (SDR) interesting. You can look it up on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

The audio output doesn't operate at high enough frequencies to generate radio signals. But the VGA output does. If you take direct control of the VGA hardware, or modulate the pixel data at correct intervals, you can generate RF signals. My favourite example is Fabrice Bellard (author of FFmpeg) making a DVB-T transmitter from a VGA card: http://bellard.org/dvbt/

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might get some results if you make an *induction loop*, such as the ones used in hearing aids, and connect that to your PC's audio output.

There's also an AM transmitter example using VGA output: http://www.erikyyy.de/tempest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CPU clock frequency as carrier, modulated by your PC sound card output.

Try by yourself to make a simple modulator with a resistor, or a more advance design using a diode, or an extreme modulator circuit using a single transistor, depends of your desired modulation type (CW,AM,FM,SSB,PSK...)

Last, don't forget how to feed of your antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Sound cards usually don't have a wide enough bandwidth to allow RF signal out, but you can modulate the audio from your sound card to some other RF source from your computer.

The motherboard usually have several known RF clock sources: several bus clocks and the RTC clock, and maybe the UART clock is right in the SW band. You can try tap off one of those crystals and use that as the carrier of your audio broadcasting.

Anyway it is always easier to roll your own radio modulator from several transistors and a crystal of your own than tapping off your motherboard.

Comment: Note that the output of a trivial DAC is rich in overtones well into RF, such that you probably can make a transmitter from a resistive ladder DAC clocked at audio sample rates - however the DACs usually used on sound cards utilize both upconverting architectures and filtering to reduce this.